# How do I have a floating image in Rmarkdown html output?

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown

I have a rmarkdown file that has a html output. I need to have my companies logo floating at the top. How would I do it? Same as the floating table of contents that rmarkdown has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put HTML into RMarkdown files. So you can just wrap your image in a `div` with the appropriate `style` CSS. Something like:

```
<div style="position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0;">
  ![](mylogo.png)
</div>
```

to have float at top-right. You may also need to position other elements so as the logo does not obscure them.

Comment: thank you! do you know if it possible to move the location of the floating table of contents?

Comment: I'm sure it is. You just have to identify the `div` that contains the contents and apply the appropriate styling with custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css script

```
`<script> $(document).ready(function() {
 $head = $('#header');
 $head.prepend('<img src=\"logo.jpg\" style=\"float: right;width: 200px;\"/>')}) </script>`
```